# Avplayer always start from beginning

Tags: swift, avplayer

I'm trying to make Avplayer resume from where it stopped , by make global value of type CMtime and store currenttime then use it to resume from where it stopped

My code :

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()      

             url = URL(string: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/kargopolov/kukushka.mp3")!
            let playerItem:AVPlayerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: url as URL)
            player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)


            let duration : CMTime = playerItem.asset.duration
            let seconds : Float64 = CMTimeGetSeconds(duration)

            playbackSlider!.maximumValue = Float(seconds)

            playbackSlider?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(playbackSliderValueChanged(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
            self.view.addSubview(playbackSlider!)


            player!.addPeriodicTimeObserver(forInterval: CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(1, 1), queue: DispatchQueue.main) { (CMTime) -> Void in
                if player!.currentItem?.status == .readyToPlay {
                    let time : Float64 = CMTimeGetSeconds(player!.currentTime())

                    self.playbackSlider!.value = Float (time) }}


 @IBAction func playbackSliderValueChanged(_ sender: UISlider) {

        let seconds : Int64 = Int64(playbackSlider.value )
        let targetTime:CMTime = CMTimeMake(seconds, 1)

        player!.seek(to: targetTime)

        if player!.rate == 0
        {
            player?.play()
        }

    }
```

When I try to use seek(to:)
nothing changed it also start from beginning !

I try to change currenttime by using

```
   if let currentTime = player?.currentTime() {
      player?.seek(to: times2!  )
   }
```

I didn't know why it always start from beginning
I was using AVAudioPlayer and it was much easier than AVplayer
but because I need to stream Audio I change it to AVplayer

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution ,

1. I got seconds from CMtime using this code , and add it on Unwind segue function

   ```
    let t1 = Float((player?.currentTime().value)!)
   let t2 = Float((player?.currentTime().timescale)!)
   times2 = t1 / t2 
   // time2 is a global value of  type float

   nameOfTheAudioWasPlaying = Array[SelectedRow].Title!     // nameOfTheAudioWasPlaying is also a global value of type String
   ```

2.in viewdidload I use this code

```
    if Array[SelectedRow].Title! ==  nameOfTheAudioWasPlaying {
        player?.seek(to: CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(Float64(times2), 1) )
        player?.play()


    }else {
        player?.play()

    }
```

it's a solution but not a perfect solution , everytime it re-download a audio file to resume it , that mean If I play a file and then I return to tableview then return back , it will purse and wait some second then play it from where it stopped .